# Deleting documents from Cloud Firestore automatically, without user interaction

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Cloud Firestore and I would like to delete a document if a certain date has been passed. This should happen without user needing to interact with the app. Is cloud functions a possible solution?

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's a very simple task and can be easily achieved with cloud functions. That's why they are for. You just need to setup an observer on date and trigger an event.

Comment: Cloud Functions doesn't have the ability to schedule work to execute at a particular time.  You still have to schedule it yourself.

Comment: It's not about the particular time it's about observing and then triggering on a certain event. I am doing that in my project and it's running perfectly.